# Código da função funciona no IDLE, mas o programa paralisa

Tags: python-3.x

Sou um principiante, treino no tempo livre faz uns dois meses e até agora meus programas tinham coisa de 5 linhas, bem simples. Esse programa me ensinou vários conceitos novos, e é parte de um programa maior que pretendo fazer.

```
def dicionario(palavra):
    f = open("portugues.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        if palavra in line:
            f.close()
            return "Existe"
    f.close()
    return "Nao existe"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    palavra = input('Digite a palavra a procurar: ')
    dicionario(palavra)
input()
```

Quando uso o IDLE, abro o arquivo como f, e o bloco do for funciona, retornando "Existe" desde que a palavra esteja no dicionario. Quando executo o programa inteiro, pelo Pycharm ou o próprio Python, o programa pede a palavra a buscar e depois paralisa, sem mensagem de erro. 
   OBS: o dicionário (portugues.txt) está no PYTHONPATH, no mesmo diretório que o programa. Uso Windows 8.
   O que falta? Pretendia usar essa função em outro programa via import, dá pra fazer desse jeito mesmo?

Comment: NO final tem um `input()` que é justamente para esperar para você dar um ENTER. Mesmo fazendo isto, o programa não termina?

Comment: O programa termina, mas a questão é que o código não procura a palavra. Ele só fica parado. Se eu digito o código da primeira linha f = ... até return "Existe", sem o f.close() ele funciona.

Comment: Queria manter o f.close() por causa do uso de memória. O dicionario de português é o da Mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido. O erro era meu. Eu esperava que quando eu rodasse o programa sozinho ele me desse a resposta na tela. return só retorna um valor, mas ele não se torna output na tela. Para isso, o código seria:

```
def dicionario(palavra):
    f = open("portugues.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        if palavra in line:
            f.close()
            return "Existe"
    f.close()
    return "Nao existe"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    palavra = input('Digite a palavra a procurar: ')
    print(dicionario(palavra))
input()
```

Nesse caso, com o print() envolvendo a função, ela faz exatamente o que eu queria, que era retornar na tela se a palavra existe ou não, quando rodo o módulo para testar.